# How do I make a new Moose class and instantiate an object of that class at runtime?

Tags: perl, class, runtime, moose, metaclass

After creating a metaclass using `Moose::Meta::Class->create`, how do I instantiate a real Moose class with that class as a metaclass?
(I need to create the metaclass also because I also want to apply some roles to it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metaclass is the class, of course.  If you want an instance of that class, just do:

```
my $instance = $meta->name->new
```

You might also need to make sure that $meta doesn't get collected too soon.  Generally, you do this:

```
$meta->add_method( meta => sub { $meta } );
```

That will keep the metaclass around, but you're going to leak the class if you aren't careful.  If you only do this once, it won't matter; if you do it thousands of times, you could get yourself into trouble.

Much better to use something higher-level like `Moose::Meta::Class::create_anon_class` or `MooseX::Traits`.

Comment: ah yes thank you jrockway :) I didn't even know what $meta->name was supposed to do, that is *HIGHLY* , I repeat, *HIGHLY* unintuitive for a method name... oh well ... the world of software

Comment: @xxxxxxxx - uh, `name` just returns the name of the package/class.  How is that unintuitive?  See http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-MOP/lib/Class/MOP/Package.pm

Comment: You could also use `new_object` on the metaclass. http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Class-MOP-1.12/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm#Object_instance_construction_and_cloning

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this answers this or your other SO question `How do I build a Moose class at runtime, add a method to it, apply a role to it and instantiate it once? How would you approach this?` at [Building a Moose class at runtime and tuning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415367/building-a-moose-class-at-runtime-and-tuning-it) but have a look at:

- [`MooseX::SingletonMethod`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-SingletonMethod/)

It may do what you want.  Or you may find it useful to peer into our it works.

The documentation does provide links to blog posts I made while coming to grips with building this module so you may find those helpful also.

Here is an brief code example of MooseX::SingletonMethod:

```
{
    package Foo;
    use MooseX::SingletonMethod;
    sub bar { say 'bar' }
}

my $baz = Foo->new;
my $bar = Foo->new;

$baz->add_singleton_method( baz => sub { say 'baz' } );

$baz->bar;   # => bar
$bar->bar;   # => bar

$baz->baz;   # => baz
$bar->baz;   # Throws can't find baz error
```

/I3az/